# Mail merge script that continues to loop and not end at last record

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub SaveBatchToUnitDirectories()
    Dim SuccessfulSave As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 0
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
        While .DataSource.DataFields("Current_Posted_Unit") <> ""
            SuccessfulSave = SaveIndividualFile
            Counter = Counter + 1
            .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Wend
    End With
    MsgBox ("Finished creating " & Counter & " documents")
End Sub
```

The code does not terminate after the last record it continues to produce. I am using the code to produce a word and pdf document for each mail merge and place these in separate folders. This function code is working correctly.

Comment: If it doesn't have any records left, what is it "continuing to produce"?

Answer (score 0):

The test for exiting the loop is invalid. When the code hits the last mail merge record and `wdNextRecord` is called again, it stays on the last record. So the data field can never return an "empty string" (unless the field happens to not have any content in the data source).

Instead, you can test the values of `ActiveRecord` before and after assigning to `wdNextRecord` as in the following code.

```
Sub SaveBatchToUnitDirectories()
    Dim SuccessfulSave As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim lastRecord As Long, nextRecord As Long
    Counter = 0
    lastRecord = 0
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
        Do
            SuccessfulSave = True
            Counter = Counter + 1
            lastRecord = .DataSource.ActiveRecord
            .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
            nextRecord = .DataSource.ActiveRecord

        Loop While lastRecord <> nextRecord
    End With
    MsgBox ("Finished creating " & Counter & " documents")
End Sub
```